# Chunked transfer encoding: How to make content invalid

Tags: http, google-chrome, browser, http-headers, chunked-encoding

I need to use **chunked** transfer encoding and I am dealing with possible error issues during generating the content. In case some error occur during the processing the content I am sending, I need to make (partial) content, which has been already sent, invalid. In **IE10** I was able to force browser to do that with **trailing** header

```
Refresh: 0; url=http://
```

but in **Chrome** I am unable to find any solution, as it seems that **trailing headers** are not implemented in this browser.

What are my options? How can I inform browser and/or user that downloaded file is invalid (so it should not be opened or saved)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Response sent in chunked transfer encoding and indicating errors happening after some data has already been sent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203379/response-sent-in-chunked-transfer-encoding-and-indicating-errors-happening-after)