# What would client receive through Squid when request timeout after it had received a header "200 OK"

Tags: http, proxy, squid

As I know, squid would send a `504 gateway timeout` when request timeout. But what if the client has already received a response header `200 ok`. I mean when the response data is sent back in chunked encoding.

**For example**: header `"200 ok"` body part `"a"` body part `"b"` body part `"c"`. After receiving `"200 ok"` and `"a"`, request timeout happen, what would squid do this time, would it send a `504 gateway timeout` back to the client ? If so, can the client received this header `"504 gateway timeout"` since it has already received a header `"200 ok"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the connection times out mid way through the request, you will not get a 504 error.

Comment: hi, remudada, what if you'v already received the 200 response header?

Comment: Alexis, If i read the specs correctly, if you have already gotten a 200 ok response, and then part of the multipart request, you are not going to get a 504 response now.

Comment: A Similar question with relevant discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203379/response-sent-in-chunked-transfer-encoding-and-indicating-errors-happening-after