# php, chunked transfer encoding: fail http connection

Tags: php, http, error-handling

Let us assume, we are generating a web page with *PHP* on *apache* and we want the browser to display the page progressively while the script still runs. We can do this by (possibly [adding some padding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16909228/1534459) and) calling [`flush()`](http://php.net/flush), which generates chunks using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked;`.

Now if an error occurs during the processing, in order to indicate this to the user, we need to [abort the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17203961/1534459). So:

**How can we close the http connection without sending the final empty chunk?**

Alternatives, which we do not want to consider are

- using JavaScript to display the error
- using HTTP trailers