# Nodejs: handling errors while piping data to a client

Tags: node.js

I have a node http server that's streaming a large amount of data from an upstream source to a client.  My code looks like:

```
handleRequest = function(req, res) {
    var readable_stream = fetchDataFromUpstream();
    res.statusCode = 200;
    readable_stream.pipe(res);
}
```

My upstream source can emit errors.  What's the proper way of handling them?  Ideally I'd want to log the error and send a 500-status response to the client reporting the problem.  However if the error happens mid-way through reading the original data, it's too late to set the correct status, right?  I don't want to wait til I have all the data in memory before starting to send it to the client, since it's a lot of data.  Is there a clean way of handling this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it turns out what I'm looking for is chunked transfer encoding (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), and that the way of indicating an error mid-transfer is to close the connection to the client (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17203961/534086)

Answer (score 0):

I would think a callback to fetch your data would be more efficient. Just convert your fetchDataFromUpstream() to handling callbacks by using a function as the first argument like so (I shortened the name)

function fromUpstream(cb) {
  /* ... */
  if (err) return cb(new Error(err));
  cb(null, data);
}

Then proceed to call it like so:

handleRequest = function(req, res) {
  fetchData(function fromUpstream(err, readableStream) {
  if (err) return new Error(err);
  res.statusCode = 200;
  readableStream.pipe(res);
  });
}

Not certain of you have already examined the documentation but the above is example is one.

Your other bet could be to bind an event emitter

https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

Comment: The reason I'm using a pipe instead of a callback is to avoid having all the data in memory, since it can be multiple megabytes of memory...

Comment: Hmmm. Perhaps you should rephrase your question