# Access to HTTP/2 trailers in a browser

Tags: javascript, browser, http2, fetch-api

Is there any browser that currently supports accessing trailers in an HTTP/2 response?

For example, the latest Fetch API specs mention that trailers are exposed via Response.trailer. Is there a browser that supports that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find a test case at http://wpt.fyi/fetch/api/response. See the results row for the test file `response-trailer.html`, and see also http://wpt.fyi/fetch/api/response/response-trailer.html.

Based on those results and their failure messages, it looks like there aren’t any browser engines that currently support [`Response.trailer`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-response-trailer-promise).

But there are open browser feature bugs for it which you might want to follow:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1339096
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=691599